# Adding "-" after into phone number

Tags: java

I'm currently working with getting a phone number from a JtextField, the problem i'm having is that after three digits are entered I want to add a "-" after the third integer is added then another "-" after the sixth integer is added. I'm not exactly sure how to do this. So far I am only checking the digits and making sure they are numbers. I'm pretty sure i should add something here,

```
homeNum.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            String homeValue = homeNum.getText();
            if (e.getKeyChar() >= '0' && e.getKeyChar() <= '9' || e.getKeyChar() == '-' || e.getKeyChar() == '\b') {


                      homeNum.setEditable(true);
                        message.setText("");

        } 
            else {
                homeNum.setEditable(false);
                message.setText("* Enter only numeric digits(0-9)");

                 }

        }
```

I was thinking about adding something like this in but the problem is that I can't delete it if I wanted too.

```
 if(homeValue.length()==3)
    {
       homeNum.setText(homeValue+"-");
    }
```

Anything help/pointers would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do it is this.. You monitor the number of times a key has been pressed. When it gets to 3, you setText to whatever you have there plus a `-` Now there are other things to consider like when the backspace has been pressed, you need to subtract one from your counter rather than adding.

Do the same for about 3-4 special keys(like not adding anything when enter is pressed).

You can do these in the background if you have a look at the SwingWorker..

Good luck

Comment: No idea what Swing Worker does.

Comment: Have a look at this http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of online tutorials to help with this:

```
public class TextVerifyInputRegularExpression {

/*
   * Phone numbers follow the rule
   * [(][1-9][1-9][1-9][)][1-9][1-9][1-9][-][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]
   */
  private static final String REGEX = "[(]\\d{3}[)]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  private static final String template = "(###)###-####"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  private static final String defaultText = "(000)000-0000"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Usearegularexpressiontoverifyinputaphonenumberisused.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an idea to work with different textboxes, like when you fill in a key-code for software-registration.